# independent gallery not related to an entry

Tags: channel-images

We are using channel-images for all our websites, but facing one big questions which always comes up.

A gallery is always created per entry, also folder of the gallery is named by the ID of the entry.

Our wish would be to create independent galleries, folder not named by id, but rather by the name of the gallery. afterwards, galleries are linked like relationships to entries. so one gallery can be linked to multiple entries, instead of creating the gallery again.

anybody in here stubmbled over that usecase we would like to have? if yes, how did you solved it or did we overlook some feature in channel images?

Best, Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time since I used Channel Images, but from your description it sounds like your scenario and issue is that each gallery is assigned to a content page entry...?

Why not have a "galleries" channel, then each entry is named as you would want the gallery. You then have all the images associated with that gallery entry. Within the content entries, you have a relationship field linked to the galleries channel - which obviously lists the nice name of each gallery. Then you can select multiple content entries with the same gallery without duplication. Your template tags access the channel images via the relationship field tag instead of directly.